# Splitting a command in PicoCLI

Tags: java, command-line, annotations, picocli

I'm using `picocli` to implement a cli tool and I've got a command which looks like the following.

`mainCommand subCommand <parameter1>:<parameter2> parameter3`

The question I have is how to map the `parameter` and `parameter2` as picoCli parameters using the picoCli annotation. The following is my approach on the annotations.

```
@CommandLine.Parameters(index = "0", split = ":")
private List<String> moduleParam;
```

Is the above the correct way to annotate the parameters or is there a better way on implementing the annotation. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` attribute can be used for both named options and positional parameters.

What you’re doing looks fine to me.